# useing better-scroll in vue, but it shows a blank sometimes

Tags: vue.js

Whe I use the plugin, better-scroll, to do a slider in vue, But it sometimes shows a blank. I do not know why. Can anyone give me a suggestion?
There have a inevitable problem. When I first into this page, the slider shows a blank.

Comment: I removed that snipped since it was empty, but you should show some code to let us help you

Comment: thanks,and I have solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

use const imgWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth instead of const imgWidth = this.$refs.sliderItemImg[0].clientWidth;